# Django checkbox do not return nothing

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I mading a project and i need to get checkbox values in sequence, but django do not return anything when that checkbox are unchecked.
how can i do that return False instead of nothing?

forms.py

```
class myFormExemple(forms.Form):
    checkbox = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

views.py

```
def MyViewExemple(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST.getlist('checkbox'))
    context = {
        'form': myFormExemple
    }
    return render(request, "cadastro/myHTMLTemplate.html", context)
```

and myHTMLTemplate.html:

```
<form method="post" id='form'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.checkbox}}          
    <button type="submit">save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: If the checkbox is not checked, the POST request will indeed *not* contain the name of that checkbox, that is how the HTML form works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the checkbox is not checked, the POST request will indeed *not* contain the name of that checkbox, that is how the HTML form works.

You can however validate and clean the data with your form, and transform this into a boolean with:

```
def MyViewExemple(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = myFormExemple(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data['checkbox'])
    context = {
        'form': myFormExemple()
    }
    return render(request, "cadastro/myHTMLTemplate.html", context)
```

We thus construct a form with `request.POST` as data source, and then if the form is valid, we can obtain a boolean with `form.cleaned_data['checkbox']`.

Django's forms are thus *not* only used to render a form, but also to process data of a form, validate that data, and convert the data to another type.